# softlayer api: How to get kvm console info?

Tags: api, vpn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, kvm

I'm developing softlayer api about softlayer vpn. Now I'd like to get the host IP, port, account and password about the kvm console on the portal. I want to know the method to get the infomation. 
regards~
As follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information using following mask in the [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject) method.

```
mask[consoleIpAddressRecord[ipAddress[ipAddress],port],operatingSystem[passwords]]
```

The complete REST call should be:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[device_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[consoleIpAddressRecord[ipAddress[ipAddress],port],operatingSystem[passwords]]

Method: GET
```

Also you can get same data separately by using the methods  [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getSoftwareComponents](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getSoftwareComponents)
 and [Softlayer_Virtual_Guest::getConsoleIpAddressRecord](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getConsoleIpAddressRecord) as following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[device_id]/getSoftwareComponents?objectMask=mask[passwords]
```

And

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[device_id]/getConsoleIpAddressRecord?objectMask=mask[port,ipAddress[ipAddress]]
```

**About Bare Metal servers**

Take account you need to be into SoftLayer VPN to start a remote access through KMV Console, you can use following REST call to get access information:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[device_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,remoteManagementAccounts,remoteManagementUsers,remoteManagementComponent]
```

I hope this help you.